# how to set pwdMaxAge for a single user in OpenLdap

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-16.04, password-policy

If I do this, it is applicable to all users.

```
ldapadd -v -H "ldaps://hostName/" -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -f pwdMaxAge.ldif 

dn: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: pwdMaxAge
pwdMaxAge: 3000
```

Tried the below ldif to set pwdMaxAge for an existing user:

```
ldapadd -v -H "ldaps://hostName/" -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -f pwdMaxAge_user.ldif

dn: cn=test2,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
cn: test2
uid: test2
pwdMaxAge: 300
```

It gives:

```
ldap_initialize( ldaps://hostName:636/??base )
add objectClass:
    device
    pwdPolicy
    top
add pwdAttribute:
    userPassword
add cn:
    test2
add pwdMaxAge:
    300
adding new entry "cn=test2,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: attribute 'uid' not allowed
```

It adds a new CN if i remove UID. but doesn't help setting the pwdMaxAge for the user. how do i set it correctly?

**Edit:**
Started creating individual policies:
cat ppolicy_individual.ldif

```
dn: cn=fin_user,ou=Policies,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
cn: fin_user
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 300
pwdInHistory: 0
pwdMaxFailure: 0
pwdLockout: FALSE
pwdMinLength: 0
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

cat pwdPolicySubentry.ldif

```
dn: cn=test2,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: pwdPolicySubentry
pwdPolicySubentry:  cn=fin_user,ou=Policies,dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

```
# ldapmodify -v -H "ldaps://hostName/" -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -f pwdPolicySubentry.ldif 
ldap_initialize( ldaps://hostName:636/??base )
add pwdPolicySubentry:
    cn=fin_user,ou=Policies,dc=mydomain,dc=com
modifying entry "uid=test2,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
modify complete
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The generic error "Object class violation , attribute 'attribute_name' not allowed" means that you're trying to set an attribute that is not not defined in the ObjectClasses available for that entry.

In other words, you first need to add an ObjectClass that provides the attribute, before you can set it. The `uid` attribute is provided by a number of different object classes.

From https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Uid

> `uid` is used as MUST (a required attribute when using that object
>   class) in:
>
> - posixAccount
> - shadowAccount
> - sambaSamAccount
> - dicAppInfo
>
> Used MAY in:
>
> - Person
> - organizationalPerson
> - inetOrgPerson

But selecting and using one of those Object classes will not only make the `uid` available, they will usually also require other attributes to be set. So pick with care

When you amend your ldif and try for instance the posixAccount object class

```
dn: cn=test2,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
objectClass: PosixAccount
pwdAttribute: userPassword
cn: test2
uid: test2
pwdMaxAge: 300
```

And you will also need to set the `uidNumber` ,  `gidNumber` and `homeDirectory`

Comment: sorry, adding `PosixAccount`, `uidNumber` other attributes didn't help. After some research, looks like i'll have to use `pwdPolicySubentry` to get it working - http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html